# Charts not showing on Crystal Reports Viewer in WebForm

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-viewer

After days of struggling, I finally have the viewer showing the images on it's icons and buttons, and showing the report nicely. However, as soon as it comes to a chart, all it it shows is a border and that little icon that shows there is supposed to be an image. Inspecting the image URL and trying to show that image in its own tab yields as little success.

What could I look at or do to get my charts showing properly?

Comment: It seems like you are using a Visual Studio web application, rather than deploying your reports with Crystal Reports Server or BusinessObjects Enterprise.  Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct, @craig.

Answer (score 3):

Found this response on SAP's forum, related to a similar-sounding issue:

> Since your dynamic images are okay it is likely the sscsdk80.dll (our
>   charting engine) which is the problem. You'll find this in the bin or
>   win32_x86 directory with the rest of your Crystal Reports dlls. It
>   needs to be registered with regsvr32.dll because it is a COM dll. Try
>   registering it to see if it helps.
>
> If not, use Process Monitor to watch your system. Filter the results
>   for your application (likely w3wp.exe because it is a web app). Then
>   show only the results for Process and Thread activity. You'll want to
>   look at the Load Image entries and look for stuff that never
>   successfully loads - such as the sscsdk80.dll.

Source: [Charts not showing on report](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1846489)

Also relevant: [Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2005 deployment trouble](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/jschreuder/archive/2007/12/10/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2005-deployment-trouble.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried assigning the "NETWORK SERVICE" account write permissions to `C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\dynamic_images` ?

is this row present in your `web.config` ?

```
<system.web> 
  <httpHandlers> 
     <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/> 
  </httpHandlers> 
</system.web>
```